# Is there a way to remove all UIActions from a UIControl?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

or is there a way to check whether a UIControl has any UIActions?

Sometimes I want to change a UIControl's behavior.
When using target-action, I can do it like this

```
button.removeTarget(nil, action: nil), for: .touchUpInside)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTouchUpInside()), for: .for: .touchUpInside)
```

Comment: What's the main purpose in your case? What's the goal of it?

Comment: @AhmadF I updated the description above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using [`enumerateEventHandlers`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/3600987-enumerateeventhandlers):

```swift
button.enumerateEventHandlers { action, targetAction, event, stop in
    if let action = action {
        // This is a UIAction
        button.removeAction(action, for: event)
    }
    if let (target, selector) = targetAction {
        // This is target / action
        button.removeTarget(target, action: selector, for: event)
    }
    stop = true // Ends iterating early if you are done
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Taking what [jrturton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/852828/jrturton) has said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71615412/6512773), you can turn it into a small extension:

```
extension UIButton {
    func removeAllActions() {
        enumerateEventHandlers { action, _, event, _ in
            if let action = action {
                removeAction(action, for: event)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And now you can just call `removeAllActions()` on your UIButton to have the same effect.

Answer (score -2):

Why not you are using `view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`? It will remove all the interaction ability of a view

Comment: This is necessary when reusing cells in UICollectionViewCell or UITableViewCell. You don't know if the cell that is dequeued is the same cell you had before and it would trigger the wrong action. Also this isn't an answer :-)